# flash builder unable to open file

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, flash-builder, mxml

I am new to adobe flash builder and I am making a mobile flex project.
In my project so far I have a simple two page layout with buttons to go forwards and back. It's a simple hello world just to test.

I wrote an action-script that uses the camera on the phone and want to attach it to a button call so the camera opens when pressed. I have looked all over the internet but cannot find a solution for this on android and would appreciate any links for any tutorials as-well.

My button call looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Camera">
    <!-- The file I want to include -->
    <fx:Script source="includes/Camera.as"/>
    <!-- Declarations -->
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <!-- alignment for buttons -->
    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
        <!-- Button that will take the user to camera -->
        <s:Button label="Capture" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <!-- Button to navigate back to the main page -->
        <s:Button label="Back" click="navigator.popView()" styleName="back" />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:View>
```

This is my error:

> 1068: Unable to open included file: C:\Users\denis\Adobe Flash Builder
>   4.6\app3\src\views\includes\Camera.as.

Includes is a folder I created.
As I stated I could not find any tutorials and I am new to this so apologies for noob questions.

Comment: just to make sure,is the file in the path the compiler searches it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you create the includes folder? My guess is that you created it in your `app3` directory, and not as a subdirectory of `src\views`.

Comment: The includes folder is outside the source but when I put it into the source folder I get the same error

Comment: But did you put it in src or in src\views?

Comment: I created a new folder in src. The src now contains (default package),includes and views

Comment: That is not the correct location to create the includes folder, if you look at the error message it shows that it is searching in app3\src\views\includes for the Camera.as file. So you should place the includes folder inside the view folder.

Comment: That worked! I took out the Camera.as and put it in views as-well as updating links. Thanks